# Why can't android:onClick recognize the specfied function?

Tags: android

Java Code:-

```
package com.example.plannerv1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayNotes extends AppCompatActivity {
    handledatabaseonhomescreen handle_db_notes = new handledatabaseonhomescreen();
    private int key;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_notes);
        Intent incomingintent = getIntent();
        key = incomingintent.getIntExtra("key",-1);
        displaydate(key);genanddisplay();
    }
    protected void addanote(View v)
    {
        Intent goback = new Intent();
        goback.putExtra("returnkey",-100);
        goback.putExtra("datewas",key);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,goback);
        finish();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent intent)
    {
        genanddisplay();
    }
}
```

XML code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayNotes"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/dmy"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="6sp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/displaynote">
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:text="Add Note"
        android:onClick="addanote"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method addanote(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

I can't figure out why the onClick tag doesn't attach the button to the specified function.

I tried to Google the problem but nothing could help me. I tried changing the name and checking if the files are linked but nothing helps.

And I'm sorry about the ugly formatting on the error but stackoverflow wouldn't let me post.

AndroidStudio gives this warning:-

```
Method 'addanote' in 'DisplayNotes' has incorrect signature less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Checks if the method specified in onClick XML attribute is declared in related activity
```

Answer (score 3):

You `addanote()` function must be `public`, not `protected`:

```
public void addanote(View v)
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#java

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't help. both public and protected don't work. I must add that I had messed with the gradle for adding firebase , could that have caused some issue?  The same code minus one new activity(for firebase use) worked fine

Answer (score 0):

As @Marcin mentioned, you should use `public` instead of `protected`. Also, you can use a different but better approach, add a listener on the `Button`:

Add an `id` attribute to the Button, then define the listener in the `onCreate()` method.
XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="addNote"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:text="Add Note"/>
```

Then Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Button addNote = findViewById(R.id.addNote);
    addNote.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            //Your code to be implemented when button is clicked.
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to use this function due to some restrictions. Any idea about why the error happens even though i defined the function?

Comment: @asds_asds There won't be any fluctuations in the result produced by using this code. These are the two same ways to produce similar results.

Answer (score 0):

The 'MainActivity' activity had a function with the same name and parameters and changing 'addanote' to something else somehow solved the problem. I had no idea it would interfere with the 'DisplayNotes' Activity. Needs to be public though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method public as mentioned here

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#java

The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
Be public
Return void
Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

the code is working fine after making it public

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7k80.png)